# Неверный пароль, ошибка в Delphi

Tags: delphi

Как сделать, чтобы при проверке правильности пароля на кнопке SpeedButton выскакивало окошко с шапкой, например, "Системная ошибка", а в самом окошке например, "Неверный пароль". У меня так

```
procedure TForm1.SpeedButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if edit1.Text = '123' then
    PostMessage(FindWindow(Nil, 'test.exe'), WM_QUIT, 0, 0)
  else
    ShowMessage('Неверный пароль');
  end;
end.
```

Как сделать шапку окошка "Ошибка", вместо названия файла?

Comment: Во-первых, повтор http://hashcode.ru/questions/105517
Во-вторых, хватит плодить виртуалов, лучше почитайте книжку

Answer (score 1):

**Winapi:**

```
SetWindowText( handle, text)
```

**Пример:**

```
SetWindowText( FindWindow(nil,'Form1'), 'NewCaption!')
```

А еще лучше использовать **MsgDialog:**:

```
MessageDlg('Ошибка!',mterror,[mbYes,mbCancel],0);
```

**P.S**

Это называется не "шапкой", а заголовком окна.

**UPD**

Тогда вам поможет **MessageBox**

```
procedure TForm1.SpeedButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
if edit1.Text='123' then
PostMessage(application.handle, WM_QUIT, 0, 0)
else
MessageBox(handle,'Ошибка!','Системная ошибка!',1);
end;
end
```

Comment: Спосибо конечно за инфу, но мне немного другое нужно.
Вводишь пароль, если пароль правельный, то форма закрывается, если неправельный, то вылетает модальное оконко в нём написанно "Неправельный пароль". А заголовок этого модального окна, вместо названия файла, должно быть написанно например "Системная ошибка". Как это сделать ?